# Rails Console Differing MySQL Results

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

I am having trouble using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with Rails. I think I have my Ruby code down but when I enter it into the `rails console` I get one result and when I copy the produced MySQL I get another result. An entire column (value) is missing in the `rails console`. Why is it that the SQL is the exact same but I am getting different results? Ideally, I want the results to include the value column. As always any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Rails Console Response**

```
2.0.0-p353 :023 > SecurityItem.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN  security_role_permissions ON security_role_permissions.security_item_id = security_items.id  AND security_role_permissions.role_id ='1'").select("security_items.name, security_role_permissions.value")

 SecurityItem Load (0.7ms)  SELECT security_items.name, security_role_permissions.value FROM `security_items` LEFT OUTER JOIN security_role_permissions ON security_role_permissions.security_item_id = security_items.id AND security_role_permissions.role_id ='1

=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation 
[#<SecurityItem id: nil, key: "ChangePassword", name: "Change Password">, 
 #<SecurityItem id: nil, key: "AddUsers", name: "Add Users">, 
 #<SecurityItem id: nil, key: "UpdateUsers", name: "Update Users">, 
 #<SecurityItem id: nil, key: "DeleteUsers", name: "Delete Users">]>
```

**MySQL Response**

```
mysql>  SELECT security_items.name, security_role_permissions.value FROM `security_items` LEFT OUTER JOIN security_role_permissions ON security_role_permissions.security_item_id = security_items.id AND security_role_permissions.role_id ='1';

+-----------------+-------+
| name            | value |
+-----------------+-------+ 
| Change Password |     1 |
| Add Users       |  NULL |
| Update Users    |  NULL |
| Delete Users    |  NULL |
+-----------------+-------+
```

Comment: Why are you even bothering using ActiveRecord?

Comment: How can I do a straight up query using Rails? I thought the preferred way is to use ActiveRecord?

Comment: You should probably start with the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). You rarely need to be writing SQL queries for basic stuff like this. Because your naming is all fubar, it's hard to say what your models look like or what your intent is here, but something like `SecureItem.where(role: Role.find(1)).all` would be a lot more ActiveRecord-style way of doing this.

Comment: And by the way, `key` is not what ActiveRecord expects a foreign key column to be named. It's going to expect a foreign key on `SecurityItem` pointing to a `Role` to be named `security_items.role_id`.

Comment: `role_id` and `key` both have an index on them. Key is used throughout the application. I can't reference an integer in this case because the maintenance of keeping track of which integer is for what item is too many.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question. You're refusing to read the documentation (i.e. familiarize yourself with the code you're asking about) and your further comments have clarified that you're not interested in a solution to a problem, but instead analysis of the behavior of Rails for the sake of it.

Comment: @coreyward I have modified my code and my migrations and I still get the same result. Please see the updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the attributes from the SecurityItem class appear in the return result. However, you can access the attributes from the joined table through the 'attributes' method.

```
security_items = SecurityItem.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN  security_role_permissions 
ON security_role_permissions.key = security_items.key  AND
security_role_permissions.role_id ='1'").select("security_items.name, 
security_items.key, security_role_permissions.permission")

security_items.each { |security_item| puts security_item.attributes['permission'] }
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. I get the following `NameError: undefined local variable or method `attributes' for main:Object`

Comment: Is there anyway to get it in the same response, like one query and to not need the each or is that not possible? This worked but just want to see if there is not a better way.

Comment: The 'permission' attributes are there in the returned object, they are just not displayed in the return text. If you want them to be displayed in one query I would create a function to chain onto the end of the query and format the data how you want to see it. I don't know any other way to get the attributes from a joined table without looping over the objects and using the 'attributes' method.